# IE issues from 8 to 11 on Magento

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, megamenu, browser, internet-explorer

My website www.giftsonclick.com is not working on IE. The megamenu is not clickable. Whereas other magento websites are working. We have followed a custom theme but not able to debug the issue.

Regards,
Richa.

Comment: any console errors?